# cf.net exception and other logging

Tags: logging, windows-mobile, compact-framework, log4net

I want to add some logging capability to a cf.net application running on WM6 Pro.  I'm looking at logging exceptions and some of the more sensitive sections of code.   I would like to have logs stored both locally (i.e. on the device) and also have them reliably uploaded to a server as well (they will need to be queued, my app is occasionally connected).

Does anyone know if this possible with log4net or will I have to write my own logging system?  Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use log4net for this, DO NOT use the UDP appender option to log to a remote server.  If the WM device is connected to a PC via ActiveSync and accessing the net through the PC, attempting to use UDP will crash ActiveSync in a way that requires a reboot of the PC and a soft reset of the WM device.  I had a demo go horribly wrong because of this (we lost a huge contract).

log4net may be great in other environments, but I've found it to be a PITA and not worth the trouble in Windows Mobile.  You're better off writing your own simple Logger class that uses a TextWriter to dump info into a text file (for local logging) or calls a webservice function on a remote server.  You have total control over what gets written where, and you don't need any Chainsaw nonsense just to read your logs.

Comment: Ah the joys of mobile development and people hack-porting desktop libs to the CF.

Comment: Thanks MusiGensis.  I was thinking of just spewing each event out to an xml file in a folder with a completely separate exe just waking up the device every so often and sending the files to a webservice (no file notifications in CE).  I suppose I could fire off the exe from my code too.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do that. Just write custom appender that checks if server is available and stores data in sqlite if not.

http://karlagius.wordpress.com/2008/01/02/writing-a-custom-appender-for-log4net/

Answer (score 0):

SQL CE (Compact Edition) supports replication.  You can store the exceptions locally, then synchonize the local datastore with a central server when connected.  Some details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171850.aspx).

Comment: I'd avoid this approach. Writing to a SQL CE database is more likely to fail than writing to a text file, and (although MS doesn't advertise this) SQL CE replication is unreliable when the network connection is dropped during replication (which happens quite a bit with mobile devices).

Comment: Thanks for your input Dave but I agree with MusiGenesis.  It's the SQLCE and SQLCE replication issues that I'm mainly interested in logging :)